# how to use effective Enumerable.Repeat

Tags: c#, linq, linq-expressions

i just want to use this query initialization at other code location :

```
 var post = Enumerable.Repeat(new
            {
                Id = default(int),
                Title = string.Empty,
                Publisher = string.Empty,
                ToUser = string.Empty,
                PublishDate = default(DateTime?),//need to default(DateTime)
                IsFile = default(bool),
                CategoryName = string.Empty,
                status_name = string.Empty,
                Group_name = string.Empty,
                FileSize = default(long?)
            }, 0).ToList();
```

I have declared one common post query. Now I just want `PublishDate` to be `default(DateTime?)` or `default(DateTime)`.

Can I set it with nullable and also non-nullable? When initializing this query it needs non-nullable datetime.

**-------------------------Updated--------------------------**

here i want nullable datetime

```
   post = db.Posts.Where(p => (p.ToUser_id.Equals(user_id) || p.ToUser_id.Equals(null)) && p.User_id != user_id).OrderByDescending(p => p.Sent_Datetime).Select(p => new
                    {
                        Id = p.Id,
                        Title = p.Title,
                        Publisher = db.Users.Where(u => u.Id.Equals(p.User_id)).Select(u => u.First_name + ' ' + u.Last_name).FirstOrDefault(),
                        ToUser = db.Users.Where(u => u.Id.Equals(p.ToUser_id)).Select(u => u.First_name + ' ' + u.Last_name).FirstOrDefault(),
                        PublishDate = p.Sent_Datetime,//nullable date time field
                        IsFile = p.IsFileAttached,
                        CategoryName = db.Categories.Where(c => c.Id.Equals(p.Category_id)).Select(c => c.Category_name).FirstOrDefault(),
                        status_name = db.Status.Where(s => s.Id.Equals(p.status_id)).Select(s => s.status_name).FirstOrDefault(),
                        Group_name = db.Groups.Where(g => g.Id.Equals(p.group_id)).Select(g => g.Group_name).FirstOrDefault(),
                        FileSize = p.TotalFileSize
                    }).FilterForColumn(ColumnName, SearchText).ToList();
```

here i want non - nullable datetime

```
 post = db.Posts.Where(p => p.User_id.Equals(user_id) && p.ToUser_id.Equals(user_id) && p.Sent_Datetime.Equals(null)).OrderByDescending(p => p.Created_datetime).Select(p => new
                    {
                        Id = p.Id,
                        Title = p.Title,
                        Publisher = db.Users.Where(u => u.Id.Equals(p.User_id)).Select(u => u.First_name + ' ' + u.Last_name).FirstOrDefault(),
                        ToUser = db.Users.Where(u => u.Id.Equals(p.ToUser_id)).Select(u => u.First_name + ' ' + u.Last_name).FirstOrDefault(),
                        PublishDate = p.Created_datetime,//non-nullable date time field
                        IsFile = p.IsFileAttached,
                        CategoryName = db.Categories.Where(c => c.Id.Equals(p.Category_id)).Select(c => c.Category_name).FirstOrDefault(),
                        status_name = db.Status.Where(s => s.Id.Equals(p.status_id)).Select(s => s.status_name).FirstOrDefault(),
                        Group_name = db.Groups.Where(g => g.Id.Equals(p.group_id)).Select(g => g.Group_name).FirstOrDefault(),
                        FileSize = p.TotalFileSize
                    }).FilterForColumn(ColumnName, SearchText).ToList();
```

this second gives me can not convert implicitly convert type...

Comment: @Tarec I think he does understand. I think he wants to force the variable to have the same anonymous type that a later assignment will be using too.

Comment: @hvd Yes, I just got his intentions. It's just the title, that's highly confusing.

Comment: I edited the question to what I suspect the OP wants. Anyone with a better guess?

Comment: What isn't working with the code you posted?

Comment: The code simply creates an empty list, it doesn't initialize anything. It's the code at that other location that needs to initialize the property

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i need to declared one property sets to nullable or non-nullable when initialization occurs. i update my question for better understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast it to `Nullable<DateTime>`:

```
PublishDate = (DateTime?)default(DateTime),
```

For example a list with one anonymous type:

```
var post = Enumerable.Repeat(new
{
    Id = default(int),
    Title = string.Empty,
    Publisher = string.Empty,
    ToUser = string.Empty,
    PublishDate = (DateTime?)default(DateTime),
    IsFile = default(bool),
    CategoryName = string.Empty,
    status_name = string.Empty,
    Group_name = string.Empty,
    FileSize = default(long?)
}, 1).ToList();
```

Here `PublishDate` is `01.01.0001 00:00:00` instead of `null`.

Comment: The OP's code uses a count of zero, and I suspect that is intentional. In that case, your change won't make any difference. Of course, the same cast *could* be useful in the code the OP isn't showing.

Comment: @hvd: i don't understand your comment. I have changed it to 1 to show that it's working. You could also use 0 and use `List.Add`. The main point is that the type in my list has a property `PublishDate` which is of type `Nullable<DateTime>` with a default value of `default<DateTime>` instead of `null`.

Comment: i follow ur steps but it gets can not implicitly convert error at non-nullable datetime initialization.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Oh, in that case, I agree with what you're trying to say, and I misread your answer (and cannot tell whether the problem is in a confusingly worded answer, or a stupidity on my part). What I'm trying to say is that the code in the question (that you changed) doesn't need changing, since it's intended let `post` remain empty. The code that actually sets `PublishDate` should add a cast to change the type to `DateTime?`, and based on your comment, that last part is exactly what you meant too.

Comment: @Shal the code you posted doesn't affect initialization - it doesn't initialize anything. You need to post the code you *do* use for initialization at that other code location

Comment: You can implicitly convert a `DateTime` to a `Nullabele<DateTime>` due to this operator: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131346(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: In switch case i want to use it common to all cases like Inbox,OutBox,Drafts,Trashed so.

Comment: @Shal: in your second query you are not casting `p.Created_datetime` to `DateTime?` as suggested in my answer. In general both types are not compatible to each other, you cannot declare a `IEnumerable<an.type>` where the property has a `Nullable<DateTime>` and then assign a `IEnumerable<an.type>` where the property is a `DateTime`. Both properties must have the same type, therefore cast it accordingly if you want to use one method for both.

Comment: ok i understand initialize it like :  PublishDate = (DateTime?)p.Created_datetime